# App crashes on start after update xcode 4.5 and iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

After I updated to xcode 4.5 and my device to iOS 6 my app crashes on startup. On simulator it works fine but when I run it on device, it crashes.

It loads the loading screen and then crashes it says:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x2fe8b0c4:  trap   <-- Thread 1: trace   
0x2fe8b0c8:  nop
```

and

```
dyld: vm_protect(0x00001000, 0x00582000, false, 0x07) failed, result=2 for
segment __TEXT in /var/mobile/Applications/*number*-****-****-****-
*number*****/appname.app/appname
(lldb)
```

I had this problem and rebuild my entire app

---

It also Says:

`(null): PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in ___block_global_101 from /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-csulsqjo‌​qjjyyahcxrvjqbpzyxot/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GameViewController.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie –`

---

When I type BT this appears:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x2fe8e0c4 dyld`dyld_fatal_error, stop reason = trace
frame #0: 0x2fe8e0c4 dyld`dyld_fatal_error
frame #1: 0x2fe8eef2 dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 78
frame #2: 0x2fe916e8 dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1432
frame #3: 0x2fe8e330 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 608
frame #4: 0x2fe8e068 dyld`_dyld_start + 64
```

When I remove all the code from one of my .m files the app does start up so I know the problem is there but its a very very big .m file

Comment: gdb/lldb command for backtrace

Comment: Might sound stupid but I don't know how to use that

Comment: At the debugger prompt `(lldb) `, in the console, type `bt`.

Comment: Sorry didn't get to answer I was at work, I did what you said and I will edit my question please have a look :)

Comment: This is realy becoming a very annoying problem I've been having this for a week now :S

Comment: Did you try anything of this `To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie –`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that can you tell me? Just started developing

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Guard Malloc option in your scheme diagnostics. This is what caused my errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this fault after accidentally disabling dynamic linking in a C++ subproject, which results in a `-static` flag being passed to clang when compiling.

Get rid of it by switching "Enable linking with shared libraries" to "Yes" (the default) in the LLVM compiler language settings. (This removes `GCC_LINK_WITH_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES = NO` from the project file).